How to use a dictionary as parameter in a fixture
When I try to use a dictionary as parameter in a fixture I get this issue:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def user_create(hp_authentification_page,request) -> None:
        page = hp_authentification_page
        page.get_by_role("link", name="Sign up").click()
>       page.get_by_test_id("given_name").fill(request.param['given_name'])
E       AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'



I have a fixture as follow:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def user_create(authentification_page,request) -> None:
    page = authentification_page
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Sign up").click()
    page.get_by_test_id("given_name").fill(request.param['given_name'])
    page.get_by_test_id("phone_number").fill(request.param['phone_number'])
    page.get_by_test_id("family_name").fill(request.param['family_name'])
    page.get_by_test_id("email").fill(request.param['email'])
    page.get_by_test_id("password").fill(request.param['password'])
    page.get_by_test_id("submit").click()

    yield page

And I want to call this fixture in the following test:
@pytest.mark.parametrize("dict_param",[{"given_name":"test","phone_number":"+330697885878",
                                        "family_name":"test","email":"test1@gmail.com","password":"Motdepasse2023*"}],indirect=True)
def test_user_create(user_create,dict_param) -> None:
    page = user_create

So I am confused. How can I use a dictionary in a fixture? Is this the right way to use parameters in a fixture?

to parametrize a test with a fixture receiving the values before passing them to a test, change your test code as below:
@pytest.mark.parametrize("user_create",[{"given_name":"test","phone_number":"+330697885878",
                                        "family_name":"test","email":"test1@gmail.com","password":"Motdepasse2023*"}],indirect=True)
def test_user_create(user_create) -> None:
    page = user_create


I changed your parametrize name from "dict_param" to the name of your fixture which is "user_create"
